# In Chrome's Inspect Element | Network panel, what do red entries signify?

Tags: google-chrome, timeout, inspect-element

We are streaming MPEG-4 media from our servers to our app in a browser.

In what appear to be random occasions, the media assets either refuse to stream, or stream after long timeouts.  The elements that have timed out appear on Chrome's network panel in red, but there appears to be no error message associated with them.

The issue appears on multiple browsers (IE11 and Chrome v35 both repro the issue) across multiple platforms (Windows 8, Mac 10.9 and Linux), so we're assuming it's something we've done.

Note that after the resource times out (last line of screen shot), it appears to try again and streams successfully (second last line of screen shot).

Note: the issue may be cache related, in that disabling the browser cache eliminates the symptom (both the timeout and the red line item).

Can anyone enlighten us on what the red line items mean, explicitly?  Is there a place where the cause of the red line item is being logged?

[image: Chrome Network Panel Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red entry in your case means the browser (as HTTP client) aborted the connection before the server ends the HTTP response.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634678/where-to-find-the-response-video-data     Has to do with inspect element network panel